# How to get GCKViewVideoFrameInput working in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast

Trying to mirror views to chromecast with the remote display API. On Android it is well documented and easy to implement. The iOS samples/docs are less complete. I understand it only supports 15 fps but that is fine for my needs.

If anyone has gotten it to work, I'd love to see a small swift sample that shows how to mirror a simple view. I'm trying to test it with this, which shows nothing on the TV and gives the device has disconnected after a few seconds. From reading the docs, that happens when you don't send anything within the first 15 secs of getting the session.

```
    var testSession: GCKRemoteDisplaySession!

    func remoteDisplayChannel(channel: GCKRemoteDisplayChannel,
    didBeginSession session: GCKRemoteDisplaySession) {
        // Use the session.
        testSession = session
        frameInput = GCKViewVideoFrameInput(session: testSession)
        // any view
        frameInput.view = testView        
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? I'm in the same situation, but cannot yet get the receiver to display anything

Comment: @kee23 Are you setting your view container (like a UIwindow) visible? I had to set it visible and put it outside the phone screen (like at -x,-y). Since remote display is only 720p and scaled up, you can set that for the UIwindow size.

Comment: I was just inializing a view and setting it to frame input's view. Turns out I had to make it a subview of the current view before it displays. I'll mess around with the window instead since I'm trying to replicate the behavior for AirPlay. Thanks!

Comment: When you make it a subview, is it visible on the phone? I'd love to have a way of making it visible on the TV without having to do the "hack" of making the view off screen with -x -y coordinates on the phone. Google is really not any help with this stuff. Doc/examples are terrible :(

Comment: No I still have to do the same "hack", so I move it offscreen by UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds width and size. I'll update here if I find a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are strongly referencing the session as well as the frame input. Inputs have weak references to sessions (to avoid cycles between sessions and inputs). If the session is not strongly referenced and gets destroyed, you'll see black on your remote screen followed by a timeout disconnect.

Comment: Okay, by keeping track of session (updated the code above), I can send a view to the Chromecast. Is there a way (trick) to send a view that is NOT visible on the phone?

Comment: I think you can create a new UIWindow, set its size, set a root view controller containing your second screen views and use the window as the frame input view.

Comment: I only seem to get it to work if I set window.makeKeyAndVisible() which displays it on the phone screen as well. I can cheat and set the window x,y to be outside the phone screen (like at -1000,-1000) but that seems pretty terrible.

Comment: @Gabeloooooo, could you please post your implemented code ? I am going to implement this (a uiviewcontroller mirroring to a TV  for a certain time, no video/audio) , would be a great help , thanks in advance bro :)