# Chromecast is not playing the media after connecting in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chromecast, google-cast

I have tried creating a demo app to cast the video from iOS app, However, the casting is occurring perfectly as I could move the volume button it's reflecting in the chrome cast, However, it doesn't play the media but it shows its connected.

The code can be reviewed in the following git.

https://github.com/DipeshPokhrel/ChromecastDemo

The snippet that creates metadata is below (I think the portion where I am missing something )

```
GCKMediaMetadata *metadata = [[GCKMediaMetadata alloc] initWithMetadataType:GCKMediaMetadataTypeTVShow];
[metadata setString:@"Hello" forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyTitle];

[metadata setString:@"Subtitle" forKey:@"description"];
[metadata setString: @"Hello moto" forKey:kGCKMetadataKeyStudio];

[metadata addImage:[[GCKImage alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CHROMECAST_STAGING_IMAGE_URL]
                                           width:320
                                          height:480]];

[metadata addImage:[[GCKImage alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CHROMECAST_PRODUCTION_IMAGE_URL]
                                               width:320
                                              height:480]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/GoogleIO-2014-CastingToTheFuture.mp4"];
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInfo = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc]
                                  initWithContentID:[url absoluteString]
                                  streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeBuffered
                                  contentType:@"video/mp4"
                                  metadata:metadata
                                  streamDuration:0
                                  mediaTracks:nil
                                  textTrackStyle:nil
                                  customData:nil];

GCKCastSession *session =
[GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager.currentCastSession;
if (session) {
    GCKMediaLoadOptions *options = [[GCKMediaLoadOptions alloc]init];
    options.autoplay = YES;
    [session.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:mediaInfo withOptions:options];
}
```

I could see no media selected at the top.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Dragonthoughts . I have created the sample as google suggested in their documentation, I am unable to find why media is not getting played for the same. As there is no specific code for the same that's why added the sample git hub repo in the quiestion itself.

Comment: The reasons for including the code within the question are that the repo may change or the link goes stale. That means nobody else can benefit from your question in the future.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I have added the snippet that I am doubting that could be the problem , However to check complete project its there always, Once the answer is confirmed we can post the same here so that other people of the community may also be benefited.

Comment: @Dipesh, please help! I need to share only my app view, rather than playing video to an external device. I just want to share the app screen to external TV using cast SDK. Any source/API to do this ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam , Can you elaborate your problem little more

Comment: Sure, I have a fitness app and several people do workouts at a time. For them, I want to share the app screen on the TV(supported by Chromecast). Google CAST iOS SDK just letting me play video only via this SDK. I don't have video to be played, i have only view/screen(s) only to be displayed. I have played videos using this (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/integrate) with no prob. But I can not set my viewcontroller as content there. How could I achieve this?

Comment: @Dipesh https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios/issues/17

Comment: @Dipesh look at this(may be another way), GCKRemoteDisplaySession is deprecated. And I see CastRemoteDisplay is only for Android in Remote Display API. Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880866/how-to-get-gckviewvideoframeinput-working-in-swift and https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastRemoteDisplay.  Better to have this for iOS.

Comment: Shortly, I need screen mirroring in iOS(not video mirroring).

Comment: I don't see any open APIS for screen mirroring, can we extend the entire video playing frame and add everything above that as subview just to ditch the G-CAST if possible

Comment: @Dipesh, my screen is like this: https://ibb.co/wKN5qQw , this must be visible during the app use/workout time. When we play video through cast sdk, it shows the video player. How i can hide the player and show app view/screen ?

Comment: You meant to add everything to the player view as a subview. Too much work in that sense.

Comment: @JamshedAlam looks almost impossible to me, if Chromecast has to mirror the entire frame then it could be really a security threat , Only my suspect ,